# How to optimize a function which contains for loops and 20 millions rows in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, bigdata

I have a pandas dataframe df that looks like the following:

```
student_id   category_id  count
1              111        10
2              111        5
3              222        8
4              333        5
5              111        6
```

Likewise I have 20 million rows.

I want to compute the rating for each student_id. For example, let's consider a category_id “111”. We have 3 student_ids 1, 2 and 5 in this category.
student_id 1 has 10 counts, student_id 2 has 5 counts and student_id 5 has 6 counts.
The rating of each student_id for category_id is calculated by the formula:

```
(count per student_id / total number of counts per category_id) * 5
```

For student_id 1 -> 10/ 21 * 5 = 2.38

For student_id 2 -> 5/ 21 *5 = 1.19

For student_id 5 -> 6/ 21 * 5 = 1.43

Below is the function I already have to compute this:

```
countPerStudentID = datasetPandas.groupby('student_id').agg(list)
countPerCategoryID = datasetPandas.groupby('category_id').agg(list)

studentIDMap = dict()
def func1(student_id):
    if student_id in studentIDMap:
        return studentIDMap[student_id]
    runningSum = 0
    countList = countPerStudentID.loc[student_id, 'count']
    for count in countList:
        runningSum += count
    studentIDMap[student_id] = runningSum
    return studentIDMap[student_id]

#Similar to the above function
categoryIDMap = dict()
def func2(category_id):
    if category_id in categoryIDMap:
        return categoryIDMap[category_id]
    runningSum = 0
    countList = countPerCategoryID.loc[category_id, 'count']
    for count in countList:
        runningSum += count
    categoryIDMap[category_id] = runningSum
    return categoryIDMap[category_id]
```

Finally I call these two function from below:

```
#Calculating rating category-wise
rating = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    totalCountPerCategoryID = func1(row['category_id'])
    totalCountPerStudentID = func2(row['student_id'])

    rating.append((totalCountPerStudentID / totalCountPerCategoryID) * 5)

df['rating'] = rating
```

Required output:

```
student_id   category_id  count   rating
1              111        10       2.38
2              111        5        1.19
3              222        8         5
4              333        5         5 
5              111        6        1.43
```

Since the data is huge, it is taking lot of time to run this. I would like to know how to optimize this calculation

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to loop, this is a `groupby` case:

```
df['rating'] = df['count']/df.groupby('category_id')['count'].transform('sum') * 5
```

Output:

```
   student_id  category_id  count    rating
0           1          111     10  2.380952
1           2          111      5  1.190476
2           3          222      8  5.000000
3           4          333      5  5.000000
4           5          111      6  1.428571
```

Comment: @QuangHoang Thank you so much. Does this solution work with bigdata? When i tried I am getting this error `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead` and the new column 'rating' has values in 10^-5

Comment: That’s a different issue. Your `df` is a part of some bigger dataFrame. Add `.copy()` to your definition of `df`. Also search for the warning on SO.

Comment: Thanks. The error is gone after i added .copy(). Unforunately I am seeing the rating values in 10^-6 and 10^-7. When I tried this with 5 row dataframe it works wonders.

Comment: Your logic, which the code follows, is weighted mean. Of course that is expected for large data set. Think you have 10**6 student with count 10 each. Your logic would give 5e-5 for each. Maybe you should replace `'sum'` with `'max'`.

Answer (score 2):

*Good god*, don't use `iterrows` and `append`, even less so *together*.  No wonder your performance is crawling.  With `pandas`, `iterrows` should be a last resort.

You should be able to achieve this with the vectorized methods:

```
>>> df['rating'] = df['count'].div(df.groupby('category_id')['count'].transform(sum)).mul(5)
>>> df
   student_id  category_id  count    rating
0           1          111     10  2.380952
1           2          111      5  1.190476
2           3          222      8  5.000000
3           4          333      5  5.000000
4           5          111      6  1.428571
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This saves a lot of time. Does this solution work with bigdata? When i tried I am getting this error `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead` and the new column 'rating' has values in 10^-5

Comment: Yes, a vectorized approach goes a long way when applying to big data.  In regards to your question, @QuangHoang has already covered it - your current `df` might be a copy or slice of the original.